# IntelliJ IDEA console input failed when using ()

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I found a problem with the console of IntelliJ IDEA. After running the Java console application, I used the IDEA built-in console to input. It seems okay to input characters except for parenthesis (). It is okay to input according to the order of string, but when I inputted a pair of parenthesis '()' first, and move the cursor inside the parenthesis, things went wrong. I will get an unremovable character on the console, also, I can no longer input any character inside the pair of parenthesis, which definitely affects the input. How can I do with it?
Here is a screen recording GIF: [screen recording GIF (on Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MyzCm1lB4hzc-t3TCAWHrb4dZm_pDja2/view?usp=sharing)
My OS: Windows 10 20H2
IDEA version: ultimate 2018.1.6

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with parenthesis. You can also not enter "aa", move the cursor between the two letters and then add a "b" between them. This is simply not supported.

Comment: @ThomasKläger That is indeed the case, thank you. But, is there any way to input a character between two existing characters?

Comment: With the IntelliJ console: no. The windows shell (cmd.exe) supports it. Linux shells don't support it. This is something that depends entirely on the runtime environment of the JVM and is out of reach for your code.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thank you so much! And I also found that this is possible on Eclipse.